# How to add a quiz Inside a video

Tags: jquery

I have an video tutorial and I want to embed couple of multiple questions at different places in the video. All these videos are delivered through a learning management system. Hence only login users will have access to these videos. Here are my questions

Q1. How do I embed quiz questions ? I believe Camtasia has a built in option to do that. Any other alternatives :

Q2. When an user submit an answer I would like record the answers in a mySQL DB

Answer (score 0):

What first sprung to my mind would be to separate each video into several smaller videos and thereby redirect to each quiz after each 'mini video'. Otherwise I think you'd have to use Flash, or JavaScript with intervals after launching the video, pausing the video etc. which sounds fairly too complex to me.

**Graphical example:**

*Lesson 1:*

```
Video1 -> Redirect -> Quiz -> Submit -> Video2 -> Repeat till finished
```